# How do I run bcdedit from my c program?

Tags: c

I don't understand why the following code returns "'bcdedit' is not an internal or external command" when ran from a c program. bcdedit works perfectly fine on cmd line. How can I get this to work?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    system("bcdedit");
    system("TIMEOUT /T 3");
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You probably need to provide a _full_ path to the program.

Comment: I tried that as well. Still nothing. I used system("C:\Windows\System32\bcdedit.exe");

Comment: Well since it appears you're using windows, you would have to escape those backslashes.  `system("C:\\Windows\\System32\\bcdedit.exe");`

Comment: Very true. I did do that, just forgot to use it in the example.

Comment: You may need to run your program as an Administrator to launch bcdedit.exe

Comment: Re the Admin user, that doesn't result in a "no such internal or external command" error. It _runs_ fine but the executable itself complains about not enough privs.

Comment: I ran it from admin cmd prompt. Still nothing.

Answer (score 3):

It happens because when you run the `Command Prompt` via Start Menu or even the Execute window you are running the 64-bit `cmd` version, located at `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`, however when call `cmd` from your c program it calls the 32-bit `cmd` version, located at `C:\Windows\SySWOW64\cmd.exe`. **This happens because your C compiler generates a 32-bit application.**

According to MSDN:

> The %windir%\System32 directory is reserved for 64-bit applications.
>   Most DLL file names were not changed when 64-bit versions of the DLLs
>   were created, so 32-bit versions of the DLLs are stored in a different
>   directory. WOW64 hides this difference by using a file system
>   redirector.
>
> **In most cases, whenever a 32-bit application attempts to access
>   %windir%\System32, the access is redirected to %windir%\SysWOW64.**

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

If you compare both `cmd`s you will realize that they are identical, what differs are the dll's.

The problem is that Windows x64 provides a 64-bit `bcdedit.exe` in the `System32` folder, but doesn't provide a 32-bit `bcdedit.exe` anywhere. **So the 32-bit `cmd` can't run the 64-bit `bcdedit`, so it returns that this command is invalid.**

**Solution:** You can both obtain a 32-bit `bcdedit` from a Windows x86 version or you can compile a 64-bit application.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because it cannot find the executable. Either ensure your path is correct<sup>(a)</sup> or use the full path name:

```
system ("c:\\windows\\system32\\bcdedit.exe");
```

And, of course, this should go without saying: make sure you run it as an administrative user.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> You should be able to confirm this with something like:

```
system ("path");
```

Comment: I checked the path and can confirm that C:\Windows\System32 is in it.

Comment: @Andrew, what compiler are you using?

Comment: I just tired to use digital mars dmc compiler but still not working

Answer (score 0):

I think you have cut one command into two part.And I think you want to run "bcdedit.exe /timeout 3",but you give the
argument of the system command two parts, one is "bcedit.exe", another is "/timeout 3". I think you should wrote this

```
system("bcdedit.exe /timeout 3");
```

to run the command you wanted.Hope this will help you

Comment: Timeout is a separate command. Bcedit ran without arguments shows a list of options.

Comment: @Andrew I have tested the same code and the same compiler to compile the code,but my program goes correctly.You should check whether your system has the program called "bcdedit.exe"

Comment: that's strange. I have confirmed that bcdedit is there. The command line code works fine when entered straight into the command line, however, it does not work when used through the c program.